# Implementar Expressão Lambda TRUE, FALSE, AND, OR e NOT com Javascript

Tags: javascript, expressões-lambda, programação-funcional

Estava lendo sobre **lambda** [nesse artigo](http://blog.caelum.com.br/comecando-com-o-calculo-lambda-e-a-programacao-funcional-de-verdade/) e lá mostrava uns exemplos de programação funcional implementando TRUE, FALSE, NOT, AND e OR com Ruby:

```
T = lambda { |a,b| a } 
F = lambda { |a,b| b } 
display = lambda { |boolean| boolean['verdadeiro','falso']}

NOT = lambda{ |x| x[F,T] }
AND = lambda{ |a,b| a[b,F] }
OR = lambda{ |a,b| a[T,b] }
```

Como implementar os mesmos exemplos com JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você escolheu um artigo um pouco complexo para começar a entender as lambas, hein? :) Poderia ter começado com um mais simples.

Em primeiro lugar, você precisa entender o que é uma lambda: trata-se de uma função anônima, que não tem atribuído a ela um nome específico. Isso soa diferente para quem está acostumado a sempre criar funções dando nome a elas, por exemplo (em Javascript):

```
function minha_funcao() {}
```

Então, como criar uma função sem dar um nome pra ela? Tanto Javascript como Ruby permitem fazer isso (aliás, muitas outras linguagens permitem, até o Java agora na versão 8 está permitindo).

```
var funcao = function(param) {}
```

Observe que a função acima não tem um nome. Na verdade, ela foi atribuída a uma variável e o nome da variável, por mais que seja tentador, não é o nome da função, mas uma referência para essa função. Então, em que isso é útil?

```
var funcao1 = function(param) {
     alert(param);
}

function funcao2() {
    funcao1("Testando");
}
```

Você pode passar funções como parâmetro para outras funções! E aí as coisas ficam sinistras e interessantes! No exemplo acima, será exibido um alert com a String "Testando".

No Ruby, essa mesma tarefa é feita de forma diferente, usando a palavra-chave `lambda`, mas prefiro não explicar muito como se faz isso em Ruby, já que sua intenção é aprender como fazer isso em Javascript. Agora, vamos fazer os exemplos que você passou em Ruby mas em JS:

```
var T = function(a,b) { return a; };
var F = function(a,b) { return b; };
var display = function(booleano) { return booleano('verdadeiro', 'falso'); };

var NOT = function(x) { return x(F,T); };
var AND = function(a,b) { return a(b,F); };
var OR = function(a,b) { return a(t,B); };

// agora testando:
alert(display(AND(T,F))); // Vai exibir verdadeiro, como deveria.
```

Criei esse fiddle com esse exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/marloncarvalho/jttr71hu/. Esse exemplo que você trouxe é um pouco complicado de entender, mas é interessante porque faz uso das funções lambda de forma magistral.

Observe que a função guardada na variável `T` recebe dois parâmetros (duas funções lambda também) e retorna apenas a primeira função. A função em `F` retorna o segundo parâmetro. Daí em diante, ele define como seria o NOT, AND e OR usando apenas essas funções!

Caso você use jQuery, sabe que existe o método `each` (https://api.jquery.com/each/) que recebe uma função como parâmetro. Essa função que você passa é um lambda!

Comment: Perfeito! Finalmente consegui entender =D muito obrigado!

Comment: Ótima resposta. Aproveito pra dizer que na próxima versão do JavaScript (ECMAScript 6) tem uma sintaxe mais curta para funções anônimas, chamada de "arrow functions", e que já suportada no FF e no Chrome Canary. Por exemplo, vai dar pra fazer `let T = (a,b) => a;`

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu estava lendo sobre essa sintaxe nova na versão 6, muito interessante!